# How to ask 2 questions with a telegraf command and save response?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf

I need to ask 2 questions and save the response after the user calls /data command.

```js
bot.command('data',(ctx) => {
    let email;
    let password;
    
    //Something like this
    ctx.reply("Enter your email");
    email = ctx.message.text;

    ctx.reply("Enter your password");
    password = ctx.message.text;
});
```

The flow would be:

- user: /data
- bot: Enter your email
- user: example@email.com
- bot: Enter your password
- user: PasswordExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use, scene.

```
bot.command('data',(ctx) => {
    let email;
    let password;
    
    //Something like this
    ctx.reply("Enter your email");
    email = ctx.message?.text;

    ctx.reply("Enter your password");
    password = ctx.message?.text;
});
```

plug

Comment: This is not the correct answer. It's not working.